# Eigenvalue of $6$-by-$6$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am doing stability analysis on my SEIR model, but I am having some difficulties in determining the eigenvalues of the jacobian matrix:

$$ J(X^0)=\begin{pmatrix}
            -(\alpha+\lambda) & \sigma & 0 & -\beta S^0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & -(\sigma+\omega+\lambda) & 0 & \beta S^0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & -(\eta+\delta+\lambda) & \mu V^0 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & \omega & \delta & -(\gamma+\lambda) & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & \gamma & -\lambda & 0\\
            \alpha & 0 & \eta & -\mu V^0 & 0 & -\lambda
            \end{pmatrix}$$

where $S^0 = \dfrac{b}{\alpha + \lambda}$ and $V^0 = \dfrac{\alpha b}{\lambda(\alpha+\lambda)}$.

I could tell that $-\lambda$ would be two identical eigenvalues, but how to find the rest?

Comment: If you imagine the full (Leibniz) expansion of the determinant, you can see that every nonzero term must include the two bottom-right $-\lambda$ entries. And _then_ every nonzero term also has to include the top-left $-(\alpha+\lambda)$. So what is left is just the 3×3 determinant in the middle -- which itself has just 3 nonzero terms.

Comment: Have you tried to think of it as a block matrix with 3 x 3 blocks?